# Placing 2 copies of javascript on same page

Tags: javascript, namespaces, code-duplication

I have implemented some functionality using about 500 hundred lines of Javascript and some html and css. I would like to place 2 instances of this on the same page. This leads to a namespace conflict.

I can think of a tedious way of avoiding this:
* As html elements are programatically accessed by IDs in Javascript, I would need to give them different ids. I'd need 2 versions of javascript functions that reference these ids.
* I'd need separate versions of javascript state variables.

Is there a simpler way of doing this that doesn't require so much code duplication, but with different names? Is there any way to make each copy behave like a separate document in this sense ie in separate namespaces?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes: Have the outermost function of your code *accept* the `id` (or other selector) that it operates on, then just call it twice.

E.g.,

```
function doSomethingNifty(id) {
    // Your code doing nifty things with `id`
}
```

Call it:

```
doSomethingNifty("foo");
doSomethingNifty("bar");
```

Any functions you define *within* `doSomethingNifty` close over the `id` argument, and so they have access to the `id` related to the call to `doSomethingNifty` that they relate to.

Here's a complete, but very simple, example. The great thing is that this scales up easily. The pattern doesn't change, you just put more inside `doSomethingNifty`.

[Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/izIsARoc/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/izIsARoc/1/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Simple Closure Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="foo">I'm foo, click me</div>
  <div id="bar">I'm bar, click me</div>
  <script>
    function doSomethingNifty(id) {
      document.getElementById(id).onclick = showMyInfo;

      function showMyInfo() {
        alert("id = " + id + ", text = " + this.innerHTML);
      }
    }

    doSomethingNifty("foo");
    doSomethingNifty("bar");
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. I have a follow on question:

Answer (score 0):

Without going into too much detail about what you're trying to do, Refactoring it might help.

For example, Instead of having a locked down un-portable piece of code, Why not simply write the HTML first and then write the JS in a way that does the work needed.

Some things just don't scale well(for example, what happens if you wanted 4 instances on the same page?